# Qual diferença xmldocument vs xmlwriter?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Qual a diferença entre as duas classes?

Em que situação cada um se encaixa melhor?

Answer (score 6):

XmlDocument representa um XML inteiro carregado na memória, enquanto o XmlWriter é um objeto que auxilia na escrita de XML em uma stream.

### XmlDocument

Se você deseja manipular um XML, por exemplo, carregar o mesmo de um arquivo, alterar alguma parte de sua estrutura e depois salva-lo, então eu usaria o XmlDocument para isso. Com ele é possível [localizar os elementos usando XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), o que facilita imensamente a manipulação.

### XDocument

Essa classe e sua relacionadas fazem parte do .Net a partir da versão 3.5, muito mais fácil de trabalhar do que com XmlDocument e relacionados. Se você quer criar aplicações sem levar as versões anteriores do .net então essa é a forma recomendada.

Para criar uma estrutura em Xml, você só precisa de uma declaração, ao invés de ficar inserindo nós:

```
var xdocument = new XDocument(
    new XElement("elementoRaiz",
        new XAttribute("atributo1", "valor"),
        new XElement("elementoFilho", "texto do elemento filho"),
        new XElement("elementoFilho2", "texto do elemento filho 2")
    ));
```

### XmlWriter

Se você quer apenas escrever um Xml em um arquivo, por exemplo, lendo dados de uma fonte qualquer tal como um banco de dados, poderia usar o XmlWriter para ir escrevendo o XML à medida que lê os dados do banco de dados.

Comment: Obrigado @Miguel, também poderia me explicar sobre a XDocument também ? em uma breve pesquisa, a XDocument parece com a syntax mais organizada e bonita, rsrsrs

Answer (score 0):

O XmlDocument é uma classe mais complexa do que o XmlWriter, pois contém mais métodos para a manipulação do xml enquanto o XmlWriter serve basicamente para gravar esse xml.